# How to run manim examples in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, manim

I'm trying to run manim using Windows 10 and Python 3.7. I've followed the instructions from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZltiKHFWmv8&t=695s.

I downloaded MikTex and Sox and successfully installed all requirements.

```
C:\Users\...>python -m pip install -r manim\requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: argparse in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colour in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 4)) (7.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: progressbar in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 7)) (4.47.0)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 8)) (4.3.0.36)
Requirement already satisfied: pycairo in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 9)) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pydub in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 10)) (0.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 11)) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyreadline in c:\users\hallo.desktop-4ovso14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r manim\requirements.txt (line 12)) (2.1)
```

I've tried following variations to run the SquareToCircle example:

```
C:\Users\...>python -m manimlib example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\python.exe: No module named manimlib.__main__; 'manimlib' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Produces error.

```
C:\Users\...>python -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\python.exe: No module named manim.__main__; 'manim' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Produces error.

```
C:\Users\...>python3 -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
```

Does not do anything.

Adding `SquareToCircle()` to the end of example_scenes.py and running it does display things like

```
Animation 1: TransformSquare:  67%|######6   | 40/60 [00:00<00:00, 60.62it/s]
```

and finally produces

```
Played 3 animations
```

without showing the desired video.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know exactly why, but running `python -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl` in Pycharm's terminal does no produce the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are not running the manim command from the Manim directory. To do this, you must change your directory into the manim directory (probably you just have to type `cd manim` into command prompt).

Comment: If I start a command prompt out of manim directory and type `python -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl` it does not do anything.

Comment: Did you install FFmpeg and add it to path?

Comment: Yes I did add FFmpeg to system variable path.

Answer (score 0):

If you got  `Played 3 Animations`, then it is very likely that there was a `media` folder created in the same directory as the file, in which the video file will be produced.

I got the file at `.\media\videos\1440p60\SquareToCircle.mp4`.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. In my case the `example_scenes.py` does not create a `media` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had to download ffmpeg, extract it to a permanent location, and add it the `\bin` file to path advanced system properties. Then open the command prompt and type `manim render FILEPATH`.
The video will be in a folder under `Windows\system32\media\videos`.